# AccessViolationException was unhandled in EMGU CV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I always get this error when I run my program...

[image]

i'm not sure about what's wrong with my program, FYI, actually my program consist of many image processing algorithm's such as

- viola-jones, haarcascade for hand detection
- camshift + kalman filter for hand tracking
- convex hull and convexity defects for counting finger
- and other preprocessing ....

I have no idea whether these process triggering the error or not...

but when I remove convexhull / convexity defects, the errors gone...
any solution?

Edited : (added)

this is the code snippet

```
 private void ExtractContourAndHull()
        {
            using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
            {
                
                Contour<Point> contours = backproject.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST, storage);
                Contour<Point> biggestContour = null;

                Double Result1 = 0;
                Double Result2 = 0;
                while (contours != null)
                {
                    Result1 = contours.Area;
                    if (Result1 > Result2)
                    {
                        Result2 = Result1;
                        biggestContour = contours;
                    }
                    contours = contours.HNext;
                }

                if (biggestContour != null)
                {
                    //image.Draw(biggestContour, new Bgr(Color.DarkViolet), 2);
                    Contour<Point> currentContour = biggestContour.ApproxPoly(biggestContour.Perimeter * 0.005, storage);
                    image.Draw(currentContour, new Bgr(Color.LimeGreen), 2);
                    biggestContour = currentContour;
                 

                    hull = biggestContour.GetConvexHull(ORIENTATION.CV_CLOCKWISE);
                    box = biggestContour.GetMinAreaRect();
                    PointF[] points = box.GetVertices();
                    //handRect = box.MinAreaRect();
                    //image.Draw(handRect, new Bgr(200, 0, 0), 1);

                    Point[] ps = new Point[points.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
                        ps[i] = new Point((int)points[i].X, (int)points[i].Y);

                    image.DrawPolyline(hull.ToArray(), true, new Bgr(200, 125, 75), 2);
                    image.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(box.center.X, box.center.Y), 3), new Bgr(200, 125, 75), 2);

                    //ellip.MCvBox2D= CvInvoke.cvFitEllipse2(biggestContour.Ptr);
                    //image.Draw(new Ellipse(ellip.MCvBox2D), new Bgr(Color.LavenderBlush), 3);

                    //PointF center;
                    //float radius;
                    //CvInvoke.cvMinEnclosingCircle(biggestContour.Ptr, out  center, out  radius);
                    //image.Draw(new CircleF(center, radius), new Bgr(Color.Gold), 2);

                    //image.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(ellip.MCvBox2D.center.X, ellip.MCvBox2D.center.Y), 3), new Bgr(100, 25, 55), 2);
                    //image.Draw(ellip, new Bgr(Color.DeepPink), 2);

                    //CvInvoke.cvEllipse(image, new Point((int)ellip.MCvBox2D.center.X, (int)ellip.MCvBox2D.center.Y), new System.Drawing.Size((int)ellip.MCvBox2D.size.Width, (int)ellip.MCvBox2D.size.Height), ellip.MCvBox2D.angle, 0, 360, new MCvScalar(120, 233, 88), 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED, 0);
                    //image.Draw(new Ellipse(new PointF(box.center.X, box.center.Y), new SizeF(box.size.Height, box.size.Width), box.angle), new Bgr(0, 0, 0), 2);


                    filteredHull = new Seq<Point>(storage);
                    for (int i = 0; i < hull.Total; i++)
                    {
                        if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(hull[i].X - hull[i + 1].X, 2) + Math.Pow(hull[i].Y - hull[i + 1].Y, 2)) > box.size.Width / 10)
                        {
                            filteredHull.Push(hull[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    defects = biggestContour.GetConvexityDefacts(storage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ORIENTATION.CV_CLOCKWISE);
                    
                    defectArray = defects.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        private void DrawAndComputeFingersNum()
        {
            using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
            {
                int fingerNum = 0;
                
                

                #region hull drawing
                //for (int i = 0; i < filteredHull.Total; i++)
                //{
                //    PointF hullPoint = new PointF((float)filteredHull[i].X,
                //                                  (float)filteredHull[i].Y);
                //    CircleF hullCircle = new CircleF(hullPoint, 4);
                //    image.Draw(hullCircle, new Bgr(Color.Aquamarine), 2);
                //}
                #endregion


                #region defects drawing
                ***defects = new Seq<MCvConvexityDefect>(storage);***
                for (int i = 0; i < defects.Total; i++)
                {
                    PointF startPoint = new PointF((float)defectArray[i].StartPoint.X,
                                                    (float)defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y);

                    PointF depthPoint = new PointF((float)defectArray[i].DepthPoint.X,
                                                    (float)defectArray[i].DepthPoint.Y);

                    PointF endPoint = new PointF((float)defectArray[i].EndPoint.X,
                                                    (float)defectArray[i].EndPoint.Y);

                    LineSegment2D startDepthLine = new LineSegment2D(defectArray[i].StartPoint, defectArray[i].DepthPoint);

                    LineSegment2D depthEndLine = new LineSegment2D(defectArray[i].DepthPoint, defectArray[i].EndPoint);

                    CircleF startCircle = new CircleF(startPoint, 5f);

                    
                    CircleF depthCircle = new CircleF(depthPoint, 5f);
                  
                    CircleF endCircle = new CircleF(endPoint, 5f);
                    MCvFont angga = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX, 0.5, 0.5);
                   // image.Draw(defectArray[i].StartPoint.X.ToString() + " , " + defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y.ToString(), ref angga, new Point(defectArray[i].StartPoint.X, defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y), new Bgr(Color.Red));
                    image.Draw(defectArray[i].StartPoint.X.ToString() + " , " + defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y.ToString() + " , " + i.ToString(), ref angga, new Point(defectArray[i].StartPoint.X, defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y), new Bgr(Color.Red));

                    //Custom heuristic based on some experiment, double check it before use
                    if ((startCircle.Center.Y < box.center.Y || depthCircle.Center.Y < box.center.Y) && (startCircle.Center.Y < depthCircle.Center.Y) && (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(startCircle.Center.X - depthCircle.Center.X, 2) + Math.Pow(startCircle.Center.Y - depthCircle.Center.Y, 2)) > box.size.Height / 6.5))
                    {
                        fingerNum++;
                        //image.Draw(startDepthLine, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);
                        //image.Draw(depthEndLine, new Bgr(Color.Magenta), 2);
                    }


                    image.Draw(startCircle, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                    image.Draw(depthCircle, new Bgr(Color.Yellow), 5);
                    //image.Draw(endCircle, new Bgr(Color.DarkBlue), 4);
                }
                #endregion

                MCvFont font = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 5d, 5d);
                image.Draw(fingerNum.ToString(), ref font, new Point(50, 150), new Bgr(Color.White));
                hand.fingerChangedCompute = fingerNum;
            }

        }

       
        
        public MemStorage storage { get; set; }
```

orgin
take a look at DrawandComputeFingersNUm() you'll see a line

```
defects = new Seq<MCvConvexityDefect>(storage);
```

the problem will occur when I uncomment the line above..

anyone knows how to solve this problem?
any help would be appreciated..
thanks

Comment: You are not going to get results asking about debugging a program based on only the algorithms it uses.  Your question will have to be much more specific to get any useful help.

Comment: ok @antlersoft I will modify the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you know I'm the creator of the code you are using.

One of my reader find sometimes an issue similar to yours, commented my post and suggest to remove the using Memstorage and put it globally then clear the storage inside `DrawAndComputeFingersNum()` function

```
MemStorage storage = new MemStorage() //Global Declaration


private void DrawAndComputeFingersNum()
    {

            int fingerNum = 0;



            #region hull drawing
            //for (int i = 0; i < filteredHull.Total; i++)
            //{
            //    PointF hullPoint = new PointF((float)filteredHull[i].X,
            //                                  (float)filteredHull[i].Y);
            //    CircleF hullCircle = new CircleF(hullPoint, 4);
            //    image.Draw(hullCircle, new Bgr(Color.Aquamarine), 2);
            //}
            #endregion


            #region defects drawing
            defects = new Seq<MCvConvexityDefect>(storage);
            for (int i = 0; i < defects.Total; i++)
            {
                PointF startPoint = new PointF((float)defectArray[i].StartPoint.X,
                                                (float)defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y);

                PointF depthPoint = new PointF((float)defectArray[i].DepthPoint.X,
                                                (float)defectArray[i].DepthPoint.Y);

                PointF endPoint = new PointF((float)defectArray[i].EndPoint.X,
                                                (float)defectArray[i].EndPoint.Y);

                LineSegment2D startDepthLine = new LineSegment2D(defectArray[i].StartPoint, defectArray[i].DepthPoint);

                LineSegment2D depthEndLine = new LineSegment2D(defectArray[i].DepthPoint, defectArray[i].EndPoint);

                CircleF startCircle = new CircleF(startPoint, 5f);


                CircleF depthCircle = new CircleF(depthPoint, 5f);

                CircleF endCircle = new CircleF(endPoint, 5f);
                MCvFont angga = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX, 0.5, 0.5);
               // image.Draw(defectArray[i].StartPoint.X.ToString() + " , " + defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y.ToString(), ref angga, new Point(defectArray[i].StartPoint.X, defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y), new Bgr(Color.Red));
                image.Draw(defectArray[i].StartPoint.X.ToString() + " , " + defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y.ToString() + " , " + i.ToString(), ref angga, new Point(defectArray[i].StartPoint.X, defectArray[i].StartPoint.Y), new Bgr(Color.Red));

                //Custom heuristic based on some experiment, double check it before use
                if ((startCircle.Center.Y < box.center.Y || depthCircle.Center.Y < box.center.Y) && (startCircle.Center.Y < depthCircle.Center.Y) && (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(startCircle.Center.X - depthCircle.Center.X, 2) + Math.Pow(startCircle.Center.Y - depthCircle.Center.Y, 2)) > box.size.Height / 6.5))
                {
                    fingerNum++;
                    //image.Draw(startDepthLine, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);
                    //image.Draw(depthEndLine, new Bgr(Color.Magenta), 2);
                }


                image.Draw(startCircle, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                image.Draw(depthCircle, new Bgr(Color.Yellow), 5);
                //image.Draw(endCircle, new Bgr(Color.DarkBlue), 4);
            }
            #endregion

            MCvFont font = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 5d, 5d);
            image.Draw(fingerNum.ToString(), ref font, new Point(50, 150), new Bgr(Color.White));
            hand.fingerChangedCompute = fingerNum;
        storage.clear(); // clear storage allocation

    }
```

Comment: I did what you say, yes it fixed the issue, but, 
the DrawComputerFingersNum method doesn't work (it doesnt draw any circle/line and fingers counting's not working)

here's the snapshot
http://i.imgur.com/aQozV.jpg

Comment: he.... the application now is running after tweaking variable of storage... and I dont know why the code's running well..

Comment: There was a potential issues with a storage variable scope. I'm glad it works now.

Comment: *There was a potential issues with a storage variable scope* Could you expand on that a little? It does seem to fix the issue, but I can't understand why. @LucaDelTongo

Comment: @NisargShah Basically the issue could depend on the way that the memstorage memory is allocated and released every time the function DrawAndComputeFingersNum is called. With the global scope there's a sort of preallocation that prevent this issue. To get a deeper explanation I should take a look at memstorage class and the way it implement IDisposable... my original did not always work properly but it was not my fault it's a side effect of some sort of not proper object disposal....